# How to use CMake to compile *.cpp and *.cu seperately?

Tags: c++, cmake, cuda, nvcc

I want to implement a Matrix class, and I want to use CUDA to speed up matrix multiplication. But when I try to compile the source files. I meet some problems. I know that I need to use NVCC to compile the *.cu. But I don't know how to write the CMakeLists.txt to compile the *.cu and *.cpp at the same time. I've tried many ways I found on Google, but they all don't work. Here is my current CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Project_4 LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include(FindCUDA)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)

include_directories(include)
aux_source_directory(src DIR_SRCS)

file(GLOB cu *.cu)
cuda_add_executable(cuda ${DIR_SRCS} ${cu})

add_executable(Project_4 ${DIR_SRCS})

set_target_properties(Project_4 PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

Then when compiling, it will report that `CMake Error at cuda_generated_ cuda_helper.cu.o.RELEASE.cmake:282`. And if I write CMakeLists.txt in this way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Project_4 LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CUDA_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ")
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/build)

include_directories(include)
aux_source_directory(src DIR_SRCS)

find_package(CUDA REQUIRED)
include_directories(${CUDA_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30)

add_executable(Project_4 ${DIR_SRCS})

set_target_properties(Project_4 PROPERTIES
        CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)
```

Then it will report error `error: expected primary-expression before "<" token` at where I call the kernel function. 
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. I will appreciate a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this link already? https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/building-cuda-applications-cmake/

Answer (score -1):

I created an example for you. It is not based on your cmake. But it works for me maybe it helps you.

1. clone repo: git clone -b cmake_cuda_example  https://github.com/werto87/durak_computer_controlled_opponent.git
2. install: [conan dependency manager](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html)
3. Install: [cuda toolkit](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html)
4. create an empty folder called build inside the "durak_computer_controlled_opponent" folder
5. go inside this folder and inside the terminal run "conan install ..  --build missing"
6. cmake  ..
7. cmake --build .